# Ler conteúdo de um pacote netflow

Tags: java, mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta que captura todo pacote UDP que passa pelo meu firewall (um OpenBSD 5.4, simulado por uma máquina virtual), mas estou com problemas para extrair as informações que preciso desses pacotes.

Meu código é basicamente:

```
try
{
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);        
byte[] receiveData = new byte [1024];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
String sql = "INSERT INTO tabela_netflow (fluxo) values (?)";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setBytes(1,receivePacket.getData());
int row = statement.executeUpdate();
if (row > 0) 
{
   System.out.println("Pacote salvo:" +receivePacket.getData());
}

} catch (SQLException ex) 
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

O código funciona (os pacotes estão sendo devidamente salvos no banco de dados), o problema é que eu não consigo visualizar o conteúdo dos pacotes (acredito que pelo fato de estar em binário). Aqui está o que eu vejo quando clico em "abrir valor no editor" no MySQL: [image: Conteúdo Banco]

O cabeçalho do netflow tem um formato conhecido, ou seja, é possível saber os campos e quantos bytes cada um ocupa, o formato do cabeçalho é este: [Cabeçalho Netflow](http://netflow.caligare.com/netflow_v5.htm)

A tabela do meu banco é bem simples, só possui código e fluxo, onde fluxo é um varbinary(10000), ou seja, eu a princípio estou salvando o fluxo inteiro, mas desejo obter e salvar cada campo do cabeçalho em uma variável respectiva no banco, para poder manipular posteriormente.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia pegar as informações que estão neste pacote? Acredito que todas as informações estão no receivePacket.getData(), porém eu não consigo uma forma na qual eu possa separar os bytes certinho para obter cada informação contida no cabeçalho..

Lembrando que é um pacote no formato Netflow, se você tiver um cliente que envia um pacote comum (código muito parecido com este, geralmente envia uma string para o coletor), o receivePacket.getData() estará com o valor da String enviada, ou seja, não é o caso que se encaixa no meu problema.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta, você quer separar cada informação de acordo com o formato do pacote netflow. Então bastaria manipular um array de bytes:

```
private void manipularStream(byte[] dadosCabecalho) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.write(dadosCabecalho,0,2); //lê os bytes 0 e 1
    String versao=out.toString("UTF-8");
    out.reset();
    out.write(dadosCabecalho,2,2); //lê os bytes 2 e 3
    String count=out.toString("UTF-8");
    ... //faça o mesmo para os outros campos
}
```

Comment: brevleq, não deu muito certo..
A separação até que funciona, mas o out.toString("UTF-8"); retorna valores com espaço em branco nas variáveis..

Debugando, consegui ver que no conteúdo da versão teria o valor 5 e para count consegui números entre 1-30, até que deu certo, mas o sysuptime já não deu certo, e o srcaddr também não..alguma sugestão?

Comment: @Ganso você teria que tratar esses espaços em branco. Quanto aos campos que não deram certo, você está pegando o intervalo certo de bytes?